# sql server collation for multi lingual data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, multilingual, collation

I am working with sql server 2012 and its the back end for an asp.net mvc multi lingual application.

I have set the collation on the database that powers the front end to "sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as".

This database will stored, english, russian, arabic etc data and therefore I will run in the collation problems as my stored procedures that will access my data has where clauses, order by clauses etc.

I have on set of stored procedures for which I access the data for language with. I am looking for the options as how to get around my issue.

I was thinking creating a view for each set of data and specify the collation on this. I will never have the scenario where I will be querying across different languages. Alternatively I could specify the collation in the stored procedure but this will mean my stored procedures will be different for each collation.

Any suggestions or idea's as to how the collation challenge here?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you'll want all of your columns to be `nvarchar`. That will take care of your storage problems. As for sorting and filtering, then collations become important as you say.

Depending on what you're doing with the data and how many columns you need to use for filtering and sorting and how you're doing the operations, one way to do it is with dynamic sql. You can do something like

```
declare @collation sysname = 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = 'select * from person order by last_name collate ' + @collation
exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

That's not a great solution, but it works. You can also throw the collation after any field in a view, so as you mentioned, that's an option. Something like this, and then you can query it without having to specify collations.

```
create view v_Person_RU as
select first_name collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI, last_name collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI...

create view v_Person_AR as
select first_name collate Arabic_CI_AI, last_name collate Arabic_CI_AI...
```

Then you could use just pick the right view to use for querying.

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('<your_db>', 'collation')

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 t
ORDER BY string_column COLLATE database_default -- i.e. sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with appropriate collation

`collate + @collation`

thanks, hope it help