# SQL Server. Unicode. Which collation for different languages in column?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

My table has "nvarchar" column and rows with different languages. Is there way to make rules as _CI_AS for all languages ? I can see collation "Latin_","French_","Spanish_","Chinese_" etc. But what collation I have to choose ?  If I will use "Chinese_" collation what sort order will be for other languages ?

It was likely question  [sql server collation for multi lingual data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409203/sql-server-collation-for-multi-lingual-data)
but no answer for "what sort order will be for other languages ?"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx

Comment: In this article only if different collation rules used in operations.This article does't give answer for example: all my symbols in rows are Chinese and which sort order will be with  "order by xxx collation Latin_". Collation rules "Chinesse_XXX" impacts only Chinese symbols. That is true ? But which sort order for other symbols ?

Comment: That will depend on the collation you choose. There are several. The article explains that.

Comment: I choose "Latin1_General_CI_AS".  But my symbols are Chinese. Which rules sort order wil be for them ?  May be "Chinese_PRC_BIN2" or "Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_BIN2" or other ?

Comment: The last part of the collation is _CI_AS = Case-insensitive and Accent-sensitive. This is what affects the sort order without a ORDER BY clause. Have you thought about just trying it, and seeing what results you get?